# Sinatra spec test undefined local variable or method `response'

Tags: rspec, sinatra

After i configured rspec for my sinatra project, i run: `rspec ./myApp_spec.rb`. But it didn't pass. The spec log as below:

> -> rspec ./myApp_spec.rb
>
> ```
> F
>
> Failures:
>
>   1) Main API should respond to GET
>      Failure/Error: expect(response.status).to eq 200
>      NameError:
>        undefined local variable or method `response' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::MainAPI:0x007f94d23cf938>
>  # ./myApp_spec.rb:6:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
>
> Finished in 0.01261 seconds (files took 0.43698 seconds to load)
> 1 example, 1 failure
>
> Failed examples:
>
> rspec ./myApp_spec.rb:4 # Main API should respond to GET
> ```

Here is my spec_helper file:

spec_helper.rb

```
require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '..', 'myApp.rb')
require 'sinatra'
require 'rack/test'
set :environment, :test
set :run, false
set :raise_errors, true
set :logging, false

def app
  Sinatra::Application
end

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Rack::Test::Methods
end
```

Here is my spec test file: myApp_spec.rb

```
require './spec_helper'

describe "Main API" do
  it "should respond to GET" do
    get '/'
    expect(response.status).to eq 200
  end
end
```

Here is my code: https://gist.github.com/williamhqs/c127e5d7018aa61cb02a

**EDIT:**

I changed `response.status` to `last_response.status` in  myApp_spec file, which seems to work. But i got the log as below, 404 NOT FOUND.

1. `response` and `last_response`, what's the difference or where is them, response is in rails_spec? Not sure.
2. The wired thing is when i access http: //localhost:3001/, it shows the right 'Hello world" content. Why it is 404?

Sorry, this is my first test in ruby/rails/sinatra.

> Failures:
>
> 1) Main API should respond to GET
>        Failure/Error: expect(last_response.status).to eq(200)
>
> ```
>    expected: 200
>         got: 404
>
>    (compared using ==)
>  # ./spec/myApp_spec.rb:8:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
> ```
>
> Finished in 0.01601 seconds (files took 0.43771 seconds to load) 1
>   example, 1 failure
>
> Failed examples:
>
> rspec ./spec/myApp_spec.rb:5 # Main API should respond to GET

**Sloution** 
 1. sinatra just use last_response, as the document example: http://www.sinatrarb.com/testing.html
 2. change app method

```
 def app   
   @app=MyApp
   #Sinatra::Application
 end
```

Hope helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

I see you've answered your own question, but it's good to have it here (and I get to add something)

From http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rack-test/0.6.3, use `last_response`.

```
before do
  # this is not part of the spec
  # but a side effect that leads to the
  # thing to be specced, so it goes in `before`
  get page
end
subject {
  last_response.body
}
it { should be_ok }
```

You can wrap that up in a shared context and pass in the `page` as a local var or a `let`.

I hate the `expect` syntax so you can work that out for yourself!